# How to implement named routes to controller with RESTful in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4

I follow Laravel 4 tutorial at http://codebright.daylerees.com/.

at codebright.daylerees.com/controllers , you can see RESTful Controllers tutorial

I arrived at advanced routing tutorial codebright.daylerees.com/advanced-routing.

There is a sample code to use Route::get with named routes. Then I try to use Route::controller to make RESTful URI with named routes.
Then, I try to write this code one **routes.php**:

```
Route::controller('my/very/long/article/route2', array(
'as'=>'article2',
'uses'=>'Blog\Controller\Article'
));
```

This is my **controller/Article.php** code:

```
<?php
namespace Blog\Controller;
use View;
use BaseController;

class Article extends BaseController
{
    public function getCreate()
    {
       return View::make('create');
    }
    public function postCreate()
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to access my/very/long/article/route2/create, it shows error

```
ErrorException
Array to string conversion
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Inspector.php
```

Any idea how to implement named routes to controller with RESTful?

Answer (score 7):

The Route::controller method accepts three arguments. Third argument is optional and it's exactly what you need. Just pass the mapping of action names to named routes as third argument.

Code example:

```
Route::controller(
    'my/very/long/article/route2', 
    'Blog\Controller\Article',
    array(
        'getCreate' => 'article.create',
        'postCreate' => 'article.create.post' 
    )
);
// now you can use route('article.create.post') to get URL of Article::postCreate action
// and route('article.create') to get URL of Article::getCreate action
```

And yep, it looks little bit overcomplicated, but still better than separate routes for each action.

This solution is actual for Laravel 4.1 (not tested in other versions).

Answer (score -2):

The controller method accepts two arguments. The first is the base URI the controller handles, while the second is the class name of the controller. Like,

```
Route::controller('my/very/long/article/route2', 'BlogController');
```

For working with RESTful API see my another post here [Laravel 4 Route Parameters for REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273329/larvel-4-route-parameters-for-rest/19273510#19273510)